# Selecting values over lists for discrete inputs in NDSolve

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving, differential-equations, control-systems

I'm currently trying to simulate a step response in a simple tank system with `NDSolve`. I would like it to start at say time 2  (the precise time is not important). As an example I use here a very simplified system

```
Controller[t_] := 100*UnitStep[t - 2]/(1 + t^2);
eqs1 = {V0'[t] == 3/(t^2 + 1) + Controller[t]};
init1 = {V0[0] == 2};
sol1 = NDSolve[{eqs1, init1}, {V0}, {t, 0, 10}];
Plot[Evaluate[{V0[t]} /. sol1], {t, 0, 10}]
```

Both this and the system without controller work perfectly fine. 
But what if I wanted to use as a coefficient for `UnitStep` a value taken from a list instead of a fixed value? 
I would like to pick a value from a list of pre-generated inputs for the coefficient, based on the current time. So as an example if I had a list of 11 elements

```
inputlist={5, 2, 5, 10, 3, 7, 2, 7, 4, 8, 2}
```

How could I tell Mathematica to pick up one of these values (sequentially if possible)? I tried

```
Controller[t_] := inputlist[[Round[t+1]]]*UnitStep[t - 2]/(1 + t^2);
```

But it doesn't work and gives the error

> The expression `Round[1+t]` cannot be used as a part specification.

Is there a clean way to step over a list like that inside `NDSolve`?

Comment: I guess `Controller[t_?NumericQ]:=..` should solve the issue!

Comment: The problem with `Controller[t_?NumericQ]:=..` is that it always evaluates `false`, so no input is ever given in the execution. The system remains without disturbance.

Comment: @antonio 1)Are you sure that this is a model of a tank system. See http://wolfram.com/xid/0jvpj762zmgvepb9y3y1-veaqch, Bernoulli's law does not end up with the equation you have. 2) Are you mixing discrete- and continuous-time dynamics?

Comment: I think that `t_?NumericQ` should be the solution to your problem (it works for me). Why do you think it always returns `False`? It clearly does not for me. You have to do a `ClearAll[Controller]` before making the new definition, otherwise the old definition will be still used for non-numeric arguments. I would finally suggest to use function names starting with lower case letters for your own functions (e.g. `controller` instead of `Controller`), there is a danger of conflicts with system symbols otherwise...

Comment: I agree with Albert Retey, please take a look at [this topic](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/5478), especially [that answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26037/5478)